# Redis - How to increment hash key when adding data?

Tags: redis, ioredis

I have a simple ioredis code, trying to create unique IDs for users:

`redis.hset("user:${user_id}", {phone_number: phone_number,username: username,password: password});`

Key should be unique. I thought I can use phone number for the user_id (key) part - but can't I just increment the user_id number starting from 0 rather than phone number? How can I do that?

Also note that I need username and password for login - phone number is just for confirmation.

Thanks for the advice.

I just tried Math.random function for user_id - but how can I sign in user with username & password?